# Diamonds are not aligned vertically on the profile page

Tags: bug, design, moderators

The diamond on the moderator profile page is not properly aligned (looks like there is “sup” tag is used) in the Communities section, e.g. [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/adam-lear):

> [image: profile]

On the Network profile page diamonds look in place:

> [image: network]

I’m using Chrome on iPad.

Comment: There is a `top: -3px` CSS rule there, but it does look fine in Chrome on desktop computer with Windows.